# How to Combine CSS in one class make usable for Blogger template

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm trying to create a text box mixture of HTML/CSS. I have CSS code for designing of text box. I want to use this code in blogger but I'm unable to combine the CSS in one class so that use in blogger. Someone help me please. Thanks.

CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Verdana;
}
.link-box,.link-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
}
.link-wrapper {
 width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
.link-box {
 width: 80%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.link-box:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #b0e0ee;
 border: 1px solid #0AA700;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-wrapper">
 <input type="text" onClick="this.select();" name="focus" required class="link-box" value="www.google.com"  readonly/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely what you mean by one class. But if you mean you can only have a class on the parent div and not on the input, this would work.

```
.link-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.link-wrapper input {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.link-wrapper input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #b0e0ee;
  border: 1px solid #0AA700;
}
```

Comment: In blogger the complete designing is stored in one xml file, so there are many other elements with same name which I provided in question. So if I call my CSS in some post then only this unique code work. Hope you understand and the answer work.

Comment: Can I minimize the html part more.? If can then please describe, Means Simply give the class name and text(value) inside it.

Comment: For example `<blockquote class="linktext">Text Here</blockquote>`